# Get bulk data from bloomberg api

Tags: c#, bloomberg

When making a request for HistoricalDataRequest on PX_LAST for a period of a month, I am getting back bulk data.  What is wrong with my syntax because I keep getting "Cannot convert SEQUENCE to Element".

```
 //FIELDS
                Element fields = security.GetElement(FIELD_DATA);
                if (fields.NumElements > 0)
                {
                    int numElements = fields.NumElements;
                    for (int j = 0; j < numElements; ++j)
                    {
                        Element field = fields.GetElement(j);

                        if (field.Datatype == Schema.Datatype.SEQUENCE || field.IsArray)
                        {
                            processBulkField(field, ticker, response);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            processRefField(field, ticker, response);
                        }


                    }
                }
```

here is the process bulk fields:  Error is on the line:  Element bulkElement = refBulkfield.GetValueAsElement(i);

```
 private static void processBulkField(Element refBulkfield, string ticker, List<BBGSecurity> response)
    {
        // Get the total number of Bulk data points
        int numofBulkValues = refBulkfield.NumValues;

        for (int i = 0; i < numofBulkValues; ++i)
        {
            Element bulkElement = refBulkfield.GetValueAsElement(i);

            // Get the number of sub fields for each bulk data element
            int numofBulkElements = bulkElement.NumElements;

            // Read each field in Bulk data
            for (int j = 0; j < numofBulkElements; ++j)
            {
                Element field = bulkElement.GetElement(j);

                response.Add(new BBGSecurity { Security = ticker, DataDate = DateTime.Parse(d_dataDate), DataSessionID = d_dataSession, Field = field.Name.ToString(), PropertyValue = field.GetValueAsString() });

            }


        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so which line is the error throwing on?

Comment: Element bulkElement = refBulkfield.GetValueAsElement(i);

Comment: Is it a compile-time or run-time error?

Comment: The [API documentation](https://bloomberg.github.io/blpapi-docs/dotnet/3.7/html/M_Bloomberglp_Blpapi_Element_GetValueAsElement_1.htm) of `GetValueAsElement` says it can only work on an array of `Sequence` or `Choice` elements. According to the if-statement in the first code block `refBulkField` could be a `Sequence`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Without knowing what request you send and how you send it it's hard to say what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `field.Datatype == Schema.Datatype.SEQUENCE` from the `if` condition, it should look like:

```
if (field.IsArray)
{
    processBulkField(field, ticker, response);
}
else
{
    processRefField(field, ticker, response);
}
```

Bulk fields are identified by property `field.IsArray = True`.
Bulk fields contains data set structured as a table with columns and rows, while SEQUENCE field contains data set represented like a C struct.